# Interbase to MSSQL ETL PK violation with no constraint on destination table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, interbase

Using SSIS to move data from Interbase to SQL. Originating table in Interbase has a Primary Key, but I did not put the PK on the destination table (for the record: PK is an int, and is unique in the table)

When I attempt to run the package, it fails with a message about violating the PK constraint... which makes no sense to me when the destination table has neither PK nor identity.

I am using an ODBC connection, ado .net source with oledb destination.

Anyone encountered this before?

Thanks!

Comment: It's been a while since you asked this question. Have you been able to resolve?